# Loose data after hit refresh button using the flutter web navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

hello i'm not familiar with the flutter navigator 2.0, i've some issue with it.
Here is my code

```
bool setup = false; // handle state of setup page
Map<String, String?> createAccountData = {}; //init a state to store data from SignUpPage
```

i'm using a function to assign data to my state in RouterDelegate

```
void _handleSetUpTapped(Map<String, String?> data) {
    setup = true;
    createAccountData = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

And here is how i've used build method of RouterDelegate

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: [
        MaterialPage(
            child: LoginPage(
                title: "Login", onSignupTap: _handleSignUpTapped)),
        if (createAccount == true && setup == false)
          MaterialPage(
              child: SignUpPage(
            title: "Sign Up",
            onSigninTap: _handleSignInTapped,
            onSetUpTap: _handleSetUpTapped,
          ))
        else if (createAccount == true &&
            setup == true &&
            createAccountData.isNotEmpty)
          MaterialPage(
              child: AccountSetup(
            account: AccountViewModel.create(
                name: createAccountData['name']!,
                email: createAccountData['email']!,
                telephone: createAccountData['telephone']!,
                password: createAccountData['password']!,
                country: createAccountData['country']!),
          ))
      ],
      onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }
        createAccount = false;
        show404 = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return route.didPop(result);
      },
    );
  }
```

Here comes my problem, when i refresh the browser then RouterDelegate calls the method **setNewRoutePath** and reset **createAccountData**

So how can i solve it please, thanks in advance